# Хедеры для модуля ядра

Tags: linux, c, visual-studio-code, kernel

В Vim написал простой модуль для символьного устройства. Пробую перейти на VS code - не находит хедеры.

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/cdev.h>
```

Начиная с linux/uaccess.h ничего не видит.  JSON VS code:

```
"includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ]
```

И вот мой makefile:

```
NAME = chrdev
obj-m += ${NAME}.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
load:
    sudo insmod ${NAME}.ko
    sudo dmesg -c
unload:
    sudo rmmod ${NAME}.ko
    sudo dmesg -c
```

Дело в том, что сборка отрабатывает. Но сам VS code не видит некоторые хедеры - что угнетает. Как это починить?

Comment: Я уже отвечал на этот вопрос. Минуточку, найду ссылку. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59325448/2511795

Answer (score 0):

Все хидеры, которые начинаются с "linux/..." - это хидеры для сборки ядра. Вы ведь написали модуль **ядра** ? Тогда он должен иметь доступ к символическим именам в ядре, которые определяются в ядерных хидерах.

На самом деле, существует целая технология (выражаясь современным языком - фреймворк) для сборки моlулей ядра - *kbuild* ). Но это отдельный разговор. В кратце - тут: http://dmilvdv.narod.ru/Translate/ELSDD/elsdd_building_kernel.html

Есть очень хорошая серия статей про разработку модулей ядра. Автор Олег Цилюрик. Посмотрите, там прямо в первой описывается, как собрать модуль в простейшем случае:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/l-linux_kernel_01/index.html

Более подробно этот процесс описан здесь:

https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0

Comment: Это все хорошо, но вы не ответили на вопрос.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat "вы не ответили на вопрос" - Надо сделать две вещи: 1) Установить хидеры ядра. Как это сделать - зависит от дистрибутива. Во многих дистрибутивах они устанавливаются автоматически, при обновлении кернела, в каталог */usr/src/kernels* 2) Указать путь к хидерам с помощью ключа -I

Comment: Автор говорит, что у него уже все собирается, значит хедеры на месте. Мы ж VSC настраиваем, так что не `-I`. И еще эти пути нужно как-то узнать...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat "так что не -I" - я не пользуюсь VSC, поэтому ответить на это вопрос не могу. Предполагаю - что где-то в свойствах проекта должен быть пункт "Добавить каталог include-файлов". Ну, нечто вроде.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - "эти пути нужно как-то узнать" - В разных дистрибутивах - по разному. Как правило, есть два места: 1) /usr/src/kernels/<весия ядра> 2) /usr/src/linux-headers-<Версия ядра>. Эту информацию можно получить (опять таки - разными способами) из информации о пакете разработки ядра. В разных дистрибутивах он тоже по разному называется. Нечто вроде linux-headers-... или kernel-devel...

Comment: Угу. Еще вариант, посмотреть на вывод `make V=1` или `make --trace`.